# Laravel Argument 1 passed to validator() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8

I had a register and login system without e mail verification on laravel. Today I wanted to add e-mail verification using this guide: https://mailtrap.io/blog/laravel-email-verification/
After everything finished I tried to register a user but I got error "Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::validator() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in /var/www/sinemori/vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/RegistersUsers.php on line 32"
I googled error and most of the answers were about use Illuminate\Http\Request; which I already use.

On my web.php I am using

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Auth::routes();
```

For /register route

Here is my RegisterController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
use RegistersUsers;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

protected function validator(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
        'surname' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required']);
}

public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validator($request);

    User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'surname' => $request->surname,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        'profile_img' => "/images/users/default_profile_picture.png"
    ]);

    return redirect()->intended('/login');
}
}
```

Here is the register.blade.php

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
<form method="post" action="{{ route('register') }}">
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control p_input">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Surname</label>
    <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control p_input">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control p_input">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control p_input">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control p_input">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Password Again</label>
    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control p_input">
</div>
<div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block enter-btn">Register</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the RegisterController.stub in `/vendor/laravel/ui/stubs/Auth`. The validator accepts an array, not a Request object, and that is what RegistersUsers passes in.

RegisterController.stub

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

And RegistersUsers

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
                ? new JsonResponse([], 201)
                : redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

So you want to match your function to the one in RegisterController.stub.

```
protected function validator(array $request)
{
    return Validator::make($request, ['name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
        'surname' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$request->validate([...])` instead of `$this->validate($request, [...])`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```php
$request->validate(['name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
        'surname' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required']);
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (RegisterController)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
use RegistersUsers;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

public function store(Request $request){
    
    $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
        'surname' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required',
]);

    User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'surname' => $request->surname,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        'profile_img' => "/images/users/default_profile_picture.png"
    ]);


    return redirect()->intended('/login');
}
}
```

I Hope This Works!